# Error while downloading missing SDK android files

Tags: android, sdk

i've got this error [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BHvx.png) while downloading missing SDK android files and i don't know what to do what can i do?

Comment: The following SDK component was not installed: 
Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3

Comment: Warning: Failed to read or create install 
properties file.